# Running geometry shader only once

Tags: 3d, geometry, directx10, geometry-shader

*(Unfortunately couldn't find the answer myself)*

**Does a neat way to cache the geometry shader results in `Direct3D10` or `OpenGL` exist?** (preferably `Direct3D10`).

I'm building my geometry based on texture sampling and I want to do it **only once.** So, when the first frame of the scene is rendered, this geometry is build and I want to substitute the geometry building process with *simple vertex / index buffer rendering.*

I hope this can be achieved without intervening into the non-shader code, but if it doesn't, what should I do? I guess the geometry can somehow be *"snapshotted"* right before the *rasterizing stage*, can it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes; the feature that does this is called "stream-out".  For D3D10, the documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205121.aspx).  It captures the geometry shader output to a vertex buffer you specify, which can then be re-used.

For OpenGL, the same functionality exists under the name "transform feedback". The relevant OpenGL spec can be found [here](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/transform_feedback.txt).